# Laptop Keys / Touchpad do not work

Tags: windows, laptop, keyboard, touchpad

When your keyboard and touchpad do not work on a laptop but the system still boots up, how do you debug and fix that.

Could the motherboard be the issue?

Comment: Are you certain that you have not locked them out using special keys

Answer (score 0):

Upon boot, your computer may display a message "press xx key to go into system setup" or similar.  Press the key.  That or F8 or sometimes F12 normally work.  Once you boot to BIOS setup, the up and down and right arrows should work.  Look for anything to do with the keyboard.  May also have something about headless (no keyboard, no monitor) operation.  Enable keyboard if disabled, if headless is set, reset it.  If you aren't sure what to do, look for a restore to default settings option.  If this DOESN'T work - can't hit F8, can't go into BIOS setup... may be a hardware failure.  May need to take in in for repair unless you feel comfortable disassembling your system.

Next step would be to get a copy of something like Ubuntu which can boot from CD or USB.  Boot that and then try your keyboard/keypad.